# How to retrieve SoC model name of an android device?

Tags: android, benchmarking, system-on-chip

How to retrieve SoC model name of an android device? E.g. `Qualcomm MSM 8974 HAMMERHEAD (Flattened Device Tree)` for Nexus 5. (E.g. CPU-Z app shows this info.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `/proc/cpuinfo` contains exactly this info.

Comment: cpuinfo does not include cpu manufacturer (eg: Qualcomm, Samsung, etc.)

Comment: @CodigosTutoriales There is a parameter in that file called `Hardware` which indirectly gives you that information. For example, on my old Karbonn A35 phone, this value was `MT6572` and on another Karbonn A30 phone, it was `MT6577` indicating that these are MediaTek SoC.

Comment: @PrahladYeri Thanks, however, it does not include model like Snapdragon <model_name>, I want to do the same that CPU-Z does to get that info.

Comment: @user5395084 did you find out?

Comment: Some devices have nothing useful here :(

Comment: On my end I only get `Qualcomm Technologies, Inc KONA`, which for me is not useful at all. I was hoping to get a 3 decimal ID number. After more Googling, still no answer on this :(

Comment: Hello from 2022 :)  Do you find answer on this question?

Answer (score 3):

There is no Android specific API that provides this info. The android CPU-Z app includes a piece of native code that finds this information.

If you want to do the same, you will need to provide your own such native code routine, though I suspect that you can probably find a routine to port in a number of open source repositories.

Comment: @zmarties I was unable to find any such repo that supports ARM.

Answer (score 1):

Try
`getprop ro.board.platform`
or
`cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/compatible`.

Comment: I got permission denied. How can I get the permission?

Comment: @TIANLUNZHU if your device is rooted with Magisk, try to do `su` to get super user permissions. Btw, if your shell has a `#` instead of `$`, then it means you already have super user permissions.